# IdentityServer4 and Data Protection in ASP.NET Core

Tags: identityserver4

We have recently started using IdentityServer4 and I read about the Data Protection in ASP.NET Core, and I am confused if I still need to keep session data if I am using IdentityServer4. We plan to have multiple machines running behind a load balancer. Can anyone point me in the right direction please? I am a bit lost and confused if IdentityServer4 will take care of the client session information? Thank you.

[ASP.Net Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Do you mean identityserver app or client app behind load balancer. And if you mean client app, specify which authentication method you are using(cookie or bearer).

Comment: Only the client app will be behind AWS ELB. We are using cookie authentication and implicit flow for now, but will switch to hybrid flow but I have not figured out how to do it yet. If it is easier to use hybrid flow please let me know. Thanks for any help as I am lost...